# argument of type “int” is incompatible with parameter of type “HTREEITEM”

Tags: c++, treeview

I'm getting error in line:

```
if (TreeView.GetItemState(item, TVIS_SELECTED) == TVIS_SELECTED)
```

It's not accepting `item`. New to using `HTREEITEM`, which is an opaque handle to a tree item in the default TreeView control on Window.

How can I get rid of the error? Only including part of the code with error:

```cpp
int item, num;

for(item = 0; item < total; ++item)
{
    if (TreeView.GetItemState(item, TVIS_SELECTED) == TVIS_SELECTED)  //error here on item
    {
        num= item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably you want `GetSelectedItem`

Answer (score 0):

The [`GetItemState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class?view=msvc-170#getitemstate) method expects an `HTREEITEM` handle to a specific tree node, but you are giving it a loop index instead.  Tree nodes are not required to be sequential, and so indexing requires more work.  The correct way to iterate a TreeView is to use methods like `GetRootItem()`, `GetNextItem()`, `GetChildItem()`, etc which all return `HTREEITEM` handles.  For example:

```
HTREEITEM item = NULL;

HTREEITEM node = TreeView.GetRootItem();

for(int num = 0; num < total; ++num)
{
    if (TreeView.GetItemState(node, TVIS_SELECTED) == TVIS_SELECTED)
    {
        item = node;
        break;
    }

    node = TreeView.GetNextItem(node, TVGN_NEXT);
}
```

However, in your particular example, it would be easier to use the [`GetSelectedItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class?view=msvc-170#getselecteditem) method instead of a manual `GetItemState()` loop, eg:

```
HTREEITEM item = TreeView.GetSelectedItem();
```